# Why is this set a half plane?

Tags: real-analysis, inner-products

The set $$\{ x: \| x - x_0\| \leq \|x-a\| , x\in \mathbb{R}^2\}$$

Where we fix the element $a$ and $x_0$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I don't see how this is equivalent to

$$\{ x: A^t x \leq b\}$$
for some $A\in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $b\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Why is this question [set-theory]? Is it because it's about sets?

Comment: Draw a picture.

Comment: I edited you question, hope I understand it correctly.

Comment: No inner product space is probably a better tag.

Comment: @MaMing The original question had nothing to do with $\mathbb{R}^2$, and the edited version is wrong. $b$ should be in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @MaMing, I actually plotted this on WOlframalpha and I got a slab. I wanted to connect the definitions.

Comment: @LordSoth, it's fine, I don't think it will change my purpose of the question. Thank you for everyone's input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you square both sides (nothing is lost as both sides are already non-negative) and cancel things, you get
$$
\|x\|^2+\|x_0\|^2-2x_0^tx\leq\|x\|^2+\|a\|^2-2a^tx,
$$
so
$$
a^tx-x_0^tx\leq\frac12\,\left(\|a\|^2-\|x_0\|^2\right),
$$
or
$$
(a-x_0)^tx\leq\frac12\,\left(\|a\|^2-\|x_0\|^2\right).
$$

Comment: Oh okay, I did that too, but I stuck with the inner products, that's why I didn't see this. Thanks

Comment: BTw, I think you are missing a $2$ on the RHS

Comment: Yes, a $1/2$ actually. Thanks.

Comment: Whoops, forgot to add those. But it really doesn't change my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can see it geometrically as follows. If $a,b$ are distinct points in the plane, it's pretty clear that the set of points that are equidistant from $a$ and $b$ is the line that bisects the segment joining $a$ and $b$. This means the points on one side are closer to $a$ and the points on the other side are closer to $b$.